# Assembly ".set" directive emitting symbol

Tags: macos, assembly, kernel, x86-64

In some kernel-mode assembly source I have a line that looks like this:

```
; excerpt #1
.set __framesize, ROUND_TO_STACK(localvarsize)
```

(`localvarsize` is a parameter to a C-preprocessor macro, if you’re wondering.) I assume that `__framesize` is a compile-time variable that is usable in `.if` statements, and is then discarded. However, I find references to a symbol named `__framesize` in the symbol table and disassembly of my kernel. The symbol is defined (as output by `nm -m`) as such:

```
; excerpt #2
0000000000000000 (absolute) non-external __framesize
```

The usage of `__framesize` in compiler-generated assembly is as such:

```
; excerpt #3
movq %gs:__framesize, %rax
movq 0x140(%rax), %r15
```

Given what I understand of my compiler and my kernel, excerpt #3 should be emitted as `movq %gs:0x140, %r15`, and that code should work. (The code that is actually being emitted from the C as excerpt #3 is causing a triple fault on the second line.)

I have two questions:

1. Should this `__framesize` symbol be emitted into my binary by the assembler when used in this fashion? If possible, how can I suppress it?
2. Would this usage of `__framesize` cause a problem like what is discussed above?

I am using GAS assembler syntax and the Xcode 7.1.1 assembler, and a Mach-O output format, if it is useful.

Comment: Is this a kernel you wrote yourself, or are you reading or modifying the source for a well-known kernel? (OS X's darwin, I assume?)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd guess he is writing a kernel extension and using something like Apple's IOKit (available in XCode)

Answer (score 2):

The GNU `as` [manual says](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Set.html#Set) that `.set` modifies the value(i.e. address) and/or type of an existing symbol.  It's synonymous with `.equ`, so it can be used to set/modify assembler macro variable, or to mess around with symbols which are also labels.

If `__framesize` is showing up in the object file, then it's probably declared somewhere else.

Try looking at the disassembly output, to see what really happened.

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but it may appear as a symbol for the purposes of debugging, but shouldn't take up physical space in the object. If it is a global symbol then it should have a memory address. Can only assume in the OPs case that it is globally defined.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  I'm just making this up from reading the docs, not practical experience.  So that sounds possible. >.<  Even a real global symbol could be pointing to memory outside any of the sections in the object file, though, right?  If it's not marked for relocation, then it's just an entry in the symbol table that only causes any harm if anything tries to use it!  (other than with a segment-override prefix).